# Azure KQL Regex capture of sentence with extract_all() for named capture groups

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to extract multiple values from a log with the following format by using the extract_all() function:

`v1=value1 v2=May 18 2021 v3=value3 v4=The dog jumps over the fence v5=192.168.1.1`

The extract_all() formatting is the following:

`extract_all(@"(?P<key>\w+)?=(?P<value>\S*)?", dynamic(["key","value"]), restconvert)`

I have tried multiple ways in order to capture the full sentence of v4, but I haven't been able to. Among others, I have used `(?P<value>\w+)?`, `(?P<value>\S* \d* \d*)?`. The latter was able to capture the date without causing any problem to the string continuity. I have also tried the logical or in the second part of the regex in order to distinguish between cases with no success.
`\w+( \w+)*` and similar variations messed up with other values, such as IP addresses and with the continuity of the string.

I am not using the parse operator because the fields change through time.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would have been a lot easier with negative lookahead, but RE2 doesn't support it apparently. This handles many spaces between words and skips spaces, but does include an extra space on the value, sometimes, if there are multiple spaces between value and the next key token.

```
print text="v1=value1 v2=May 18 2021 v3=value3   v4=The dog jumps over the fence"
| extend values = extract_all(@"(?P<key>\w+)=(?P<value>(?:\w+(?:\s?|\z))+)(?:\s|\z)", dynamic(["key","value"]
```

Results:

```
[
  [
    ""v1"",
    ""value1 ""
  ],
  [
    ""v2"",
    ""May 18 2021 ""
  ],
  [
    ""v3"",
    ""value3 ""
  ],
  [
    ""v4"",
    ""The dog jumps over the fence""
  ]
]
```

Comment: It really works! However, I would like to ask which addition can be made in order to recognize symbols (such as dots etc., in the case of IP addresses).

Comment: You can use a character group like `[\w\.]`, which includes alphanumeric + `.` character, if you know which characters you want to include. You might be able to use a negation group like `[^\_\s\n]` where you accept any character except spaces/newlines and `+` character (which you're using to break up your groups) - this would allow ANY character to be included.